# installing jupyter notebooks on macOS

Tags: python, macos, pip, jupyter

when I do a pip install jupyter notebook, which it seems to install and then I run "jupyter notebook" it tells me that "zsh: command not found: jupyter"

Also does it matter using zsh on macOS?

Any suggestions too fix this issue?
Thanks!
Johnny

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1493257/cannot-open-jupyter-notebook-in-the-new-zsh-shell-in-macos

Comment: _Also does it matter using zsh on macOS?_ It’s unclear to me what exactly you mean, but I don’t think it’s relevant to the current issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure where juypter was installed is on your execution path in the zsh shell.  (If "which jupyter" doesn't list a valid path, then that's your problem. :)

Should look something like this, but with the location on your machine:

```
(jupyter) c-67-188-202-51{rich:~/src/python/udemy/completePythonBootcamp} which jupyter
/Users/rich/src/python/udemy/completePythonBootcamp/jupyter/bin/jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. If you've installed it using `--user` try to add to your path variable in `.zshrc` a path like this `/Users/<name_of_your_user>/Library/Python/3.8/bin`. Replace `<name_of_your_user>` with name of the user and maybe you have another version of python and the folder `3.8` should be replaced with the corresponding version. It helped me. Please check if that works for you and mark the question as solved if it did.